# is there any difference between Watir Vs Watir-webdriver for handling xpath

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Below is the html from webpage i am trying to automate, When I am using Watir, it is finding the element correctly but not with watir-webdriver.

```
  <td width="87">
  <input type="image" style="height: 34px; width: 83px; border-width: 0px;" src="/test/test/img/Order-Online-Form_18.gif" id="order1_Next1" name="$Next1">
                </td>
```

I am using the below code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
browser = watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'test.com'
test = @browser.td(:xpath,"//input[@id='order1_Next1']").exists?
puts test
```

When I am using watir, it returns true but If i am using watir-webdriver, it returns false. 
Can you guys help me why watir-webdriver is not recognizing the xpath

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to locate a 'td' when you're looking for a 'button'.

And using a XPath selector is almost certainly the wrong way to locate this element.

You're much better off using the button element type with an id attribute:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.start 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18859962/qageeks.html'
b.button(:id => 'order1_Next1').exists? # => true 
b.button(:xpath,"//input[@id='order1_Next1']").exists? # => true
```

You can use the last line if you're adamant about xpath, but as you can see it's more verbose and less clear to read.

Comment: xpath also tends to be slower, more prone to user error when scripting, and nearly impossible for anyone else to understand when updating or reviewing your scripts.  Us it only if no other way works.

Comment: Is Watir the same as Watir-Webdriver ?Thanks.
PS - I don't want to make a question for this because it will be downvoted.

Comment: Same API, different browser support. Webdriver supports all the browsers, Watir only supports IE